# QlikView Text Object Formatting

Tags: qlikview

I am unable to format the text in a text object. For example, I need headers in bold, while the body of the text could be normal. Can I get any hints on this?

I know this can be achieved via extension objects, but I do not have any experience creating them.

Comment: Please could you explain what a "text box" is? Do you mean a text object, or a Table Box?

Comment: Yes, I do refer to text object.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible in QlikView 11. It has been an open development request for [quite some time](http://community.qlik.com/ideas/1880).

You have two options:

1. Use multiple text objects and lay them over each other (i.e. make the topmost one bold and its background transparent).
2. Use an extension object, however, this then restricts you to AJAX/WebView for your document. There is an existing extension (written by [Stefan Walther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120981/stefan-walther)) that has this capability [here](http://www.qlikblog.at/1579/qliktip-39-displaying-html-content-minimalistic-htmltextbox-object-extension/) ([git repo](https://github.com/QlikDev/qvMinimalisticHtmlTextBox)).